# ActiveRecord find identical set in many_to_many models

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, anti-patterns

I have an anti-pattern in my Rails 3 code and I was wondering how to do this properly.

Let's say a customer orders french fries and a hamburger. I want to find out if such an order has been placed before. To keep it simple each item can only be ordered once per order (so no "two hamburgers please") and there are no duplicate orders either.

The models:

```
Order (attributes: id)
  has_many :items_orders
  has_many :items, :through => :items_orders

Item (attributes: id, name) 
  has_many :items_orders
  has_many :orders,:through => :items_orders

ItemsOrder (attributes: id, item_id, order_id)
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :item 
  validates_uniqueness_of :item_id, :scope => :order_id
```

The way I do it now is to fetch all orders that include at least one of the line items. I then iterate over them to find the matching order. Needless to say that doesn't scale well, nor does it look pretty.

```
order = [1, 2]
```

1 and 2 correspond to the Item ids of fries and hamburgers.

```
candidates = Order.find(
  :all, 
  :include => :items_orders, 
  :conditions =>  ["items_orders.item_id in (?)", order])

previous_order = nil

candidates.each do |candidate|
  if candidate.items.collect{|i| i.id} == order
    previous_order = candidate
    break
  end 
end
```

I'm using MySQL and Postgress so I'm also open for a standard SQL solution that ignores most of ActiveRecord.

Comment: Can you please list attributes and relationships of `Order`, `Item' and `ItemOrder`?

Comment: Does my answer below help, @SjorsProvoost? Let me know if you have any problems?

Comment: @PaulRussell it would certainly be much faster than what I have now, thanks. I was just hoping there would be a solution that doesn't require redundancy (or at least one that let's the database take care of that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want to find *identical* orders, I'd be tempted to use a hash to achieve this. I'm not able to test the code I'm about to write, so please check it before you rely on it!

Something like this:
 - Create a new attribute `order_hash` in your Order model using a migration.
 - Add a `before_save` hook that updates this attribute using e.g. an MD5 hash of the order lines.
 - Add a method for finding like orders which uses the hash to find other orders that match quickly.

The code would look a little like this:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord
  def before_save
    self.order_hash = calculate_hash
  end

  def find_similar
    Order.where(:order_hash => self.calculate_hash)
  end

  def calculate_hash
    d = Digest::MD5.new()
    self.items.order(:id).each do |i|
      d << i.id
    end
    d.hexdigest
  end
end
```

This code would allow you to create and order, and then calling `order.find_similar` should return a list of orders with the same items attached. You could apply exactly the same approach even if you had item quantities etc. The only constraint is that you have to always be looking for orders that are *the same*, not just vaguely alike.

Apologies if the code is riddled with bugs - hopefully you can make sense of it!